# indirect reference of function arguments

Tags: bash

say that I have:

```
$@: arg1 arg2 arg3
```

and:

```
arg1=arg1_val
arg2=arg2_val
arg3=arg3_val
```

can I get `arg1_val arg2_val arg3_val` in one go or do I have to iterate necessarily?

```
values=()
for i in "$@"; do
  values+=("${!i}")
done
echo "${values[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should achieve the effect:

```
declare -a "values=($(printf '"$%s" ' "$@"))"
echo "${values[@]}"
# output : arg1_val arg2_val arg3_val
```

Comment: Because the expansions are unquoted, this is word-splitting and glob-expanding values rather than accurately representing them. Testing with `set -- arg1 arg2; arg1="two words"; arg2="contains * globs"; declare -a "values=($(printf '$%s ' "$@"))"`, I get a `values` that splits `two` and `words` into separate array elements, and replaces the `*` with a list of filenames in the current directory.

Comment: @Philippe It seems to me that it doesn't work: `printf '"$%s" ' "$@"` gets `$arg1 arg2 arg3` and should get `$arg1 $arg2 $arg3`

Comment: @francesc, Are you sure it's `$arg1 arg2 arg3` ?  If you run `declare -a "values=($(printf '"$%s" ' "$@"))"`, `values` will be an array like in your post containing `arg1_val arg2_val arg3_val`

Comment: @francesc, when shell printf is given more arguments than there are placeholders in its format string, it repeats the format string until all arguments are consumed. (This is effectively an implicit loop, replacing the explicit one you want to get rid of).

Comment: You both were right. I had incorrectly $1 = "arg1 arg2 arg3". THanks